# YUI Theater license

Tags: yui

What license does the videos on [YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) have ?
Just want to put them on our internal network.

Regards

Comment: This question is not about programming so is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Until you mentioned it, I personally find it surprising that YUI Theater (and probably some other videos sites as well) didn't actually put up any usage terms or licensing.

If a reasonable guess was to be made, I'd pretty much assume that all YUI Theater videos as public domain but copyrighted media. If you putting it up in your internal network (as opposed distributing it at a profit), I'm pretty sure that it's allowed as long you distributed as-is.

If there's further doubt (that you fear might step on borders of possible copyright infringement), it may be better to contact the YUI team directly.